# Bug in my view show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, model-associations

I currently develop my APP with Ruby on Rails. I make an association between 2 models. The result is good but for display my entrance in my view show i meet a problem.

Here is my code :

```
<%= @play.calendar_dates.each do |calendar_date| %>
    <li><%= calendar_date.adress_1 %></li>
    <li><%= calendar_date.adress_2 %></li>
    <li><%= calendar_date.zip %> - <%= calendar_date.town %>
<% end %>
```

In my table play I record `calendar_date` and now I want to display them in a loop `.each` but the code displays this in addition to a good table:

```
> [#<Calendar::Date id: 7, month: "", day: nil, hour: nil, week: "", play_id: 8, place: "", adress_1: "", adress_2: "", zip: "", town: "", season: "">, #<Calendar::Date id: 6, month: "Mai", day: nil, hour: nil, week: "Mercredi", play_id: 8, place: "A la mairie de bergerac", adress_1: "La Mairie", adress_2: "3 rue Degniolette", zip: "24100", town: "Bergerac", season: "2018">, #<Calendar::Date id: 5, month: "Mars", day: nil, hour: nil, week: "Mardi", play_id: 8, place: "Village santé", adress_1: "La santé Michel", adress_2: "4 rue des pigeons", zip: "24140", town: "Villemblard", season: "2018">]
```

I don't now how to discard this from my view...

Comment: It's because you're using `<%= %>` instead `<% %>`, which prints the result of applying `each` on `@play.calendar_dates`.

Comment: But that is don't work without...

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: So sorry ! I make a mistake when i was read your message... It's work !! thank you so much !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line `<%= @play.calendar_dates.each do |calendar_date| %>`, take the equal sign out after the `%`.

The equal sign means you intend it to be output.  In this case, it would output the result of `@play.calendar_data.each` which is the array you see.